# Why yum wget failed? No match for argument: wget

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

I have RHEL9,I tried

```
sudo yum install wget
```

got

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Last metadata expiration check: 0:12:43 ago on Mon 20 Feb 2023 10:04:53 AM UTC.
No match for argument: wget
```

I checked

```
yum info wget
```

got

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:37 ago on Mon 20 Feb 2023 10:14:28 AM UTC.
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

I have `epel-release`

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: It says pretty clearly: "
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register."

Comment: I can do it cli,or should go to REDHAT WEBSITE?

Answer (score -1):

you have to update your Subscription to download the dependecies. then, the dnf command should be used in rhel9 for installing packages.

dnf install package-name

refer: [https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/managing_software_with_the_dnf_tool/assembly_installing-rhel-9-content_managing-software-with-the-dnf-tool][1]